# nested_form in rails - creating a belongs_to or use existing object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I have a nested form using 2 objects, ImageComponent (a kind of wrapper with extra attributes around the asset itself) and ImageAsset (simply the asset) and the relationships are as follows

ImageAsset has_many, :image_components

ImageComponent belongs_to :image_asset

I am using Ryan Bates nested_form gem to on a form to create an ImageAsset.

The problem arises when i would like to create an ImageAsset or associate an existing ImageAsset using nested attributes from my ImageComponent form.

I currently have this set up as follows in my form

```
<legend>Image Component</legend>

<%= f.fields_for :component do |component_fields| %>
   <p>Select an existing image ...</p>
   <%= component_fields.label 'image_asset_id', 'Image' %>
   <%= component_fields.select "image_asset_id", options_for_image_select(component_fields.object.image_asset_id) %>

   <p>... or upload a new one!</p>
   <%= component_fields.fields_for :new_image_asset, ImageAsset.new do |asset_fields| %>
          <%= asset_fields.label :title %>
          <%= asset_fields.text_field :title %>

          <%= asset_fields.label :image %>
          <%= asset_fields.file_field :image  %>
   <% end %>

   <%= component_fields.label :caption %>
   <%= component_fields.text_field :caption %>
<% end %>

<%= f.hidden_field :component_type %>
<%= f.link_to_remove 'Remove Component' %>
```

The problem here is that I am posting 2 images. One being an existing image (depending on if it is a new or create action this could be nil) and the second being a newly uploaded images attributes.

My initial thought was to create a before_validation callback on the model like so (new_image_asset being an attr_accessor on the model to allow the attributes to be passed from the form)

```
if new_image_asset[:title].present? || new_image_asset[:image].present?
    image_asset = ImageAsset.new(new_image_asset)
end
```

This however still gives me an issue in that image is supposedly blank (i guess because the asset has not yet been saved)

Is there another way to do this whilst keeping validation errors on the form for the image?

The hope here was that if the user includes anything for a new image asset then it will try to create on and validate it. If there is nothing in the new_image attributes it uses whatever is in the collection select for existing ImageAsset

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance